# Word which means that a number has magnitude greater than one?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives

I am looking for a word which describes a number as having a magnitude greater than one. i.e. numbers such as 1.2, 100, 123456, -4, -1.01

Hopefully it should be usable in a sentence like this one:

> There were a number of scenarios which had negative or *greater than*
>   *one* coefficients.

Thanks in advance.

*I hope this question is suitable for English exchange, otherwise I might try Math exchange.*

Comment: Maybe something similar to "extra-unary"?

Comment: I think you're going to have to stick with:  "*There were a number of scenarios which had coefficients with magnitudes greater than one*"

Comment: Thanks for including the example sentence! I can't think of a word off the top of my head. It looks like you want an adjective, am I right?

Comment: @Jim Yeah I am thinking I might.

Comment: @sumelic an adjective would be desirable, but rephrasing it might work as well?

Comment: It may just be there as an example, but if it's specifically *coefficients* that you're interested in, you could use the fact that a coefficient greater than one is a coefficient which increases the magnitude of the value that it multiplies. I wouldn't say that it is in common use but, for example, I think the meaning of the phrase "magnitude-increasing coefficient" is clear enough. You wouldn't need the "negative", so just "a number of scenarios which had magnitude-increasing coefficients" would do.

Comment: Why not just say "... coefficients outside the unit interval"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_interval

Comment: @anemone The unit interval would exclude negative numbers, you'd need to say something like "...with magnitude outside the unit interval".

Comment: @Rupe I said _outside the unit interval_.

Comment: @anemone Yes but you didn't say "magnitude". What you said would include numbers between 0 and -1, which the OP wants to exclude. Sorry, my point may have been clearer if I'd said "the unit interval excludes *all* negative numbers".

Comment: @Rupe I'm just trying to reformulate the example sentence. Instead of "negative or greater than one coefficients", I'm suggesting "coefficients outside the unit interval". That does not address the question in the title, of course.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I was thinking in terms of a phrase which describes the set of numbers defined in the title and exemplified by the list in the first paragraph, as opposed to one which describes the same set of numbers as the example sentence (I was taking that just to be showing us the kind of sentence they want to use the phrase in). Anyway, for the OP's sake it's good to have made this clear.

Comment: The correct term is "a number with a magnitude greater than one".  Or one can substitute "absolute value" for "magnitude".  If there were a shorter term, use of the phrase "greater than one" in math texts would be about one tenth of what it is.

Comment: What kind of coefficient is this? A physical quantity, or mathematical coefficients such as in polynomials?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered symbolic syntax? For coefficients - a math concept - I'd think something like `|β| > 1` (absolute value greater than 1) would be appropriate.

If symbolic isn't an option, I'd suggest "there were a number of scenarios with *a non-directional coefficient greater than one"*. It's not open to ambiguity and works as an adjective to coefficient instead of introducing a new concept like "coefficient with a ..." does.

Comment: If these solutions are readable by the OP's target audience, than it's hard to imagine a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

It would be correct to say "...coefficients outside the closed interval [-1,1]." I'm pretty sure there's no specific adjective to modify "coefficients" that does what you want, but if I had to make one up it would be "superunital."

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the term ***absolute value***.

The phrase would be:

> ...an ***absolute value*** greater than or equal to one.

Comment: I don't think that improves on the "magnitude greater than one" in the question. To be frank I think the best solution is simply to rearrange stuff in the question to get "...coefficients with magnitude greater than one". By the way note also that your "or equal to" is out of place here - the OP wants to exclude 1 and -1.

Answer (score 0):

- "coefficients that have an absolute value  greater than one"

Comment: that is easily misparsed as "coefficients that are negative" (eg., -0.4) or "coefficients greater than one".

Comment: @MarkBrackett: I don't understand. Can you explain the misparsing a bit more? What's the difference between the intended meaning and the mis-understood meaning?

Comment: the intended meaning is "coefficients that are less than -1" or "coefficients that are greater than 1".

Comment: My bad. Mowzer is correct about absolute value.